# Env variable value got reset to original even after assigning the pom version number in jenkins script

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a scenario where i have to read the maven pom versions for different components and assign the version to docker image(TAG). But after i read the pom, assigned it to some global variable it will reset to original value in groovy jenkins script. Below is the sample. HMAP_VERSION value will 1.2.1 but when it is used in the line: `sh "docker login -u ${ART_USERNAME} -p ${ART_PASSWORD} test.com"` the value will be `UNINITIALISED`.

Can somebody tell me what might have gone wrong? This will work with single maven file which is read in env block as below:

```
environment {
    CLOADER_VERSION  = readMavenPom().getVersion()
}
```

Below is the sample of what im tring to do.

```
#! groovy

environment {
    HMAP_VERSION = "UNINITIALISED"
    CLOADER_VERSION = "UNINITIALISED"
}

stages {
    stage('Build Cloader') {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM' "rest is removed")

            dir('isa-casloader') {
                script {
                    CLOADER_VERSION = readMavenPom().getVersion()
                }
                container('build') {
                    sh '/opt/apache-maven/bin/mvn -s settings.xml -B clean install -DskipTests=true'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage ('Build Casloader Docker Image') {
        steps {
        dir('isa-casloader') {
        container('tools') {
            echo("CLOADER_VERSION=${CLOADER_VERSION}")
            withCredentials() {
                sh "docker login -u ${ART_USERNAME} -p ${ART_PASSWORD} testing.com"
                sh 'docker build -t testing.com:${CLOADER_VERSION} .'
                sh 'docker push testing.com:${CLOADER_VERSION}' 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage ('Build Heat Map Docker Image') {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', "rest is commented"])

            dir('apps') {
                container('tools') {
                    script {
                        def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom-docker.xml'
                        HMAP_VERSION = pom.version
                    }
                    echo("HMAP_VERSION=${HMAP_VERSION}")
                    withCredentials() {
                    sh "docker login -u ${ART_USERNAME} -p ${ART_PASSWORD} test.com"
                    sh 'docker build -t test.com:${HMAP_VERSION} .'
                    sh 'docker push test.com:${HMAP_VERSION}'
}}}}}}}
```

Comment: Best practice, use env.VAR_NAME if using an ENV var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. My issue got resolved. In docker context as shown below,

```
withCredentials() {
 sh "docker login -u ${ART_USERNAME} -p ${ART_PASSWORD} testing.com"
 sh 'docker build -t testing.com:${CLOADER_VERSION} .'
 sh 'docker push testing.com:${CLOADER_VERSION}' 
}
```

Login command is proper which is inside double quotes, but the next statements were in single quotes. So variables latest value was not getting resolved. When i change the statements to be inside double quotes, it worked!!

Below is the proper command:

```
withCredentials() {
 sh "docker login -u ${ART_USERNAME} -p ${ART_PASSWORD} testing.com"
 sh "docker build -t testing.com:${CLOADER_VERSION} ."
 sh "docker push testing.com:${CLOADER_VERSION}"
}
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

By my read of your code, you're mixing environment variables with variables within the Groovy context.

These lines create environment variables, which are accessible in the shell as `$HMAP_VERSION` and `$CLOADER_VERSION`:

```
environment {
    HMAP_VERSION = "UNINITIALISED"
    CLOADER_VERSION = "UNINITIALISED"
}
```

However, you're populating a Groovy variable here:

```
script {
    CLOADER_VERSION = readMavenPom().getVersion()      
}
```

To instead populate the environment variable, you'd want to use `env.CLOADER_VERSION` instead.

This changes what context the variables are evaluated in when you're calling out to shell using the `sh` directive:

```
1-> sh "docker login -u ${ART_USERNAME} -p ${ART_PASSWORD} testing.com"
2-> sh 'docker build -t testing.com:${CLOADER_VERSION} .'
3-> sh 'docker push testing.com:${CLOADER_VERSION}'
```

In line number **1** above, the command is quoted using a double quotes (`"`) which means that the variables `ART_USERNAME` and `ART_PASSWORD` are evaluating in the context of the Groovy script.

However, in lines **2** and **3** the commands are quoted using a single quote (`'`) which means that those variables are being evaluated by the shell (likely `/bin/sh`) and therefore using the values from the environment.

The easiest fix would be to ensure that values you want exposed in the shell are always accessed using the `env.` prefix in the Groovy context:

```
// set environment for CLOADER_VERSION
env.CLOADER_VERSION = readMavenPom().getVersion()
// print value of environment variable CLOADER_VERSION
echo("CLOADER_VERSION=${env.CLOADER_VERSION}")

// set environment for HMAP_VERSION
env.HMAP_VERSION = pom.version
// print value of environment variable HMAP_VERSION
echo("HMAP_VERSION=${env.HMAP_VERSION}")
```

Cheers.